# VueJS mustache data binding not working. How can I debug this?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to render VueJS data strings within HTML tags with VueJS mustaches. However, the strings don't appear to be rendering - the variable values are populating as observed within VueJS dev-tools. Any assistance on determining what must have gone wrong will be appreciated.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Doc Scan</title>

    <!--Bulma CSS-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.7.1/css/bulma.css" />

    <!-- Vue JS Production-->
    <!-- <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script> -->

    <!-- Vue JS Dev-->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="app">
        <h1 class="title is-1">Doc Scanner</h1>
        <div class="file has-name">
            <label class="file-label">
                <input class="file-input" type="file" ref="file" v-on:change="handleFileUpload()">
                <span class="file-cta">
                    <span class="file-icon">
                        <i class="fas fa-upload"></i>
                    </span>
                    <span class="file-label">
                        Choose a file…
                    </span>
                </span>
                <span class="file-name" v-if="file">
                    File is there : {{ filename }}
                </span>
                <span class="file-name" v-else>
                    No file selected
                </span>
            </label>

        </div>

    </div>

    <!--VueJS Script-->
    <script>
        var app = new Vue({
            el: '#app',

            data: {
                file: '',
                filename: '',
            },

            methods: {
                handleFileUpload() {
                    this.file = this.$refs.file.files[0];
                    this.filename = this.file.name;
                    console.log(this.filename)
                }
            }
        })
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This is working for me? I am using this image to upload: https://i.imgur.com/d1HOxKk.png

Comment: I executed this code on a CodePen and it worked just fine. Can you please update your post to use a runnable snippet? https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/ or a CodePen or StackBlitz?

Comment: @MattU Done! Snippet has been added.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I checked again - when I host this file through Python flask, it seems that the mustaches are not resolving to the data strings. However, it works fine when the HTML is opened directly within the browser. Any thoughts on why this may be happening ?

Comment: It seems like the VueJS delimiter was clashing with Python's. Re-defining the delimiter as per this post solved the issue- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45203736/how-do-i-use-flask-templating-with-vuejss-mustache-syntax. Thank you for your assistance :)

Comment: Note: the `<link>` tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in HTML.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the VueJS delimiter was clashing with Python's. Re-defining the delimiter as per this post solved the issue- stackoverflow.com/questions/45203736/…. Thank you for your assistance :)

Answer (score 0):

You should rather use [vue-cli](https://cli.vuejs.org/) in order to set up a project easily and to be able to use all the possibilities of vuejs

Then, data must be a function that returns an object.

Take a look at the documentation : https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html

```js
var app = new Vue({
            el: '#app',

            data: function() {
               return {
                file: '',
                filename: '',
               }
             },

            methods: {
                handleFileUpload() {
                    this.file = this.$refs.file.files[0];
                    this.filename = this.file.name;
                    console.log(this.filename)
                }
            }
        })
```